# ROCR package prediction function error: Number of predictions in each run must be equal to the number of labels for each ru error

Tags: r, roc

I'm trying to write a function that computes ROC AUC and PR AUC for a set of model predictions, but am getting this:

> Error in prediction(predictions_probs, true) : Number of predictions in each run must be equal to the number of labels for each run.

even though both inputs are the same length. Running the function code outside of the function also works fine. It's only when I run the code inside the function that the code complains. What could be the problem?

**Reprex:**

```r
library(PRROC)
library(ROCR)

predictions_prob_xgboost_test <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6)
true_test <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)

typeof(predictions_prob_xgboost_test)
typeof(true_test)

length(predictions_prob_xgboost_test)
length(true_test)

roc_pr_auc_calc <- function(prediction_probs, true){

  # Calculate the ROC curve
  pred <- prediction(predictions_probs, true)
  rocs <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")

  # get AUC value for each model
  auc_ROCR <- performance(pred, measure = "auc")
  roc_auc <- auc_ROCR@y.values

  roc_auc

  fg <- predictions_probs[true == 1]
  bg <- predictions_probs[true == 0]

  # PR Curve
  pr <- pr.curve(scores.class0 = fg, scores.class1 = bg, curve = T)

  pr_auc <- pr$auc.integral
  pr_auc

  return(list(roc_auc, pr_auc))
}

roc_pr_auc_calc(prediction_probs = predictions_prob_xgboost_test, true = true_test )
```

Output:

```
[1] "double"
[1] "double"
[1] 4
[1] 4
Error in prediction(predictions_probs, true) : Number of predictions in each run must be equal to the number of labels for each run.
```

Comment: I get `Error in prediction(predictions_probs, true) :  object 'predictions_probs' not found` when I run your code. Can you check you posted the correct one?

Comment: Assuming the variables inside the function are `prediction_probs` instead of `predictions_probs`. This doesn't return me an error. and returns output as 1 and 1.